# If there are fewer than 20 rows for both queries unioned together ,then show no rows

Tags: postgresql

For the query below, I would like to display the rows when they are more than 20 rows.If the rows are less than than we should not flag anything. I have tried to use count(*) to get the total number of rows.

```
select count(*) from
(select column 1,column 2
from table1
union
(select
column3,column4
from
table2)as numrows;
```

From then on I'm not sure how to proceed.I know we might need to use an if statement to restrict the number of rows from showing less than 20.

Comment: Consider using a SQL [case](https://www.sqlshack.com/case-statement-in-sql/) statement.

Answer (score 0):

Put your query in a common table expression, and select from it with a condition based on the number of rows.

```
with rows as (
  select column1, column2 from table1 union
  select column3, column4 from table2
)
select *
from   rows
where  (select count(*) from rows) > 20;
```